# SKStoreProductViewController must be used in a modal view controller SWIFTUI

Tags: swiftui

I am building a info page for my SwiftUI app. One item should open App Store, another mail. I have written  UIViewControllerRepresentable for each.

MailView works fine totally.  StoreView displays fine, but when pressed on Cancel button, throws exception

"*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'SKUnsupportedPresentationException', reason: 'SKStoreProductViewController must be used in a modal view controller'".

MailView goes fine into didFinish delegate method but StoreView does not go into didFinish delegate method, it crashes before going into this didFinish method. What am I doing wrong please?

```
import SwiftUI
import StoreKit
import MessageUI

struct InfoMoreAppsView: View {
    @State var showAppAtStore = false
    @State var reportBug = false
    @State var result: Result<MFMailComposeResult, Error>? = nil
    let otherAppName = "TheoryTest"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            HStack{
                Image(Helper.getOtherAppImageName(otherAppName: otherAppName))
                Button(action: { self.showAppAtStore = true }) {
                    Text(otherAppName)
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $showAppAtStore){
                    StoreView(appID: Helper.getOtherAppID(otherAppName: otherAppName))
                }
            }
            Button(action: { self.reportBug = true }) {
                Text("Report a bug")
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $reportBug){
                MailView(result: self.$result)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .font(.title2)
    }
}

struct StoreView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    let appID: String
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate {
        @Binding var presentation: PresentationMode
        init(presentation: Binding<PresentationMode> ) {
            _presentation = presentation
        }
        private func productViewControllerDidFinish(viewController: SKStoreProductViewController) {
            $presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(presentation: presentation)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<StoreView>) -> SKStoreProductViewController {
        let skStoreProductViewController = SKStoreProductViewController()
        skStoreProductViewController.delegate = context.coordinator
        let parameters = [ SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier : appID]
        skStoreProductViewController.loadProduct(withParameters: parameters)
        return skStoreProductViewController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: SKStoreProductViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<StoreView>) {
    }
}


struct MailView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation
    @Binding var result: Result<MFMailComposeResult, Error>?
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
        
        @Binding var presentation: PresentationMode
        @Binding var result: Result<MFMailComposeResult, Error>?
        
        init(presentation: Binding<PresentationMode>,
             result: Binding<Result<MFMailComposeResult, Error>?>) {
            _presentation = presentation
            _result = result
        }
        
        func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController,
                                   didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult,
                                   error: Error?) {
            defer {
                $presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
            guard error == nil else {
                self.result = .failure(error!)
                return
            }
            self.result = .success(result)
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(presentation: presentation,
                           result: $result)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<MailView>) -> MFMailComposeViewController {
        let mailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposeViewController.mailComposeDelegate = context.coordinator
        mailComposeViewController.setToRecipients([Constants.SUPPORT_EMAIL])
        mailComposeViewController.setMessageBody(systemInfo(), isHTML: true)
        return mailComposeViewController
    }
    
    func systemInfo() -> String {
        let device = UIDevice.current
        let systemVersion = device.systemVersion
        let model = UIDevice.hardwareModel
        let mailBody = "Model: " + model + ". OS: " + systemVersion
        
        return mailBody
    }
    
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MFMailComposeViewController,
                                context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<MailView>) {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't very "Swifty" or pretty but I got this to work without crashing by not wrapping the SKStoreProductViewController in a representable.

```
struct MovieView: View {
var vc:SKStoreProductViewController = SKStoreProductViewController()
var body: some View {
HStack(){
                                Button(action: {
                                    let params = [
                                        SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier:"1179624268",
                                        SKStoreProductParameterAffiliateToken:"11l4Cu",
                                        SKStoreProductParameterCampaignToken:"hype_movie"
                                        ] as [String : Any]
                                   // vc!.delegate = self
                                    vc.loadProduct(withParameters: params, completionBlock: { (success,error) -> Void in
                                        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                                    })
                                }) {
                                    HStack {
                                        Image(systemName: "play.fill")
                                            .font(.headline)
                                      
                                    }
                                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 6, leading:36, bottom: 6, trailing: 36))
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .background(Color(red: 29/255, green: 231/255, blue: 130/255))
                                    .cornerRadius(10)
                                }
                                Spacer()
                            }}
```

Comment: Starting iOS 15, you can use this code to prevent deprecation warning:                  UIApplication.shared.currentUIWindow()?.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: The better answer is below...

Answer (score 9):

Since I was stuck on the same thing. Here is a quick solution I found working.

```
import StoreKit
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct StoreView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
  var dismissHandler: () -> Void

  func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<StoreView>) -> StoreViewController {

    return StoreViewController(coordinator: context.coordinator)
  }

  func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: StoreViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<StoreView>) {

  }

  public func makeCoordinator() -> StoreViewCoordinator {
    .init(dismissHandler: dismissHandler)
  }
}

class StoreViewController: UIViewController {
  let coordinator: StoreViewCoordinator
  var storeController: SKStoreProductViewController?

  init(coordinator: StoreViewCoordinator) {
    self.coordinator = coordinator

    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
  }

  @available(*, unavailable)
  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    storeController = SKStoreProductViewController()
    storeController?.delegate = coordinator

    storeController?.loadProduct(
      withParameters: [SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier: ******]
    )
  }

  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    guard let storeController = storeController else {
      return
    }

    present(storeController, animated: true)
  }
}

class StoreViewCoordinator: NSObject, SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate {
  private let dismissHandler: () -> Void

  init(dismissHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    self.dismissHandler = dismissHandler
  }

  func productViewControllerDidFinish(_ viewController: SKStoreProductViewController) {
    dismissHandler()
  }
}
```

and then I am using it inside ZStack like:

```
StoreView(
 dismissHandler: { viewStore.send(.setShowingStore(false)) }
)
.isHidden(!viewStore.isShowingStore, remove: true)
```

I am using TCA, so setting a property will be different in your case

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted one. I added the itms id as a parameter.

Comment: You could replace the dismissHandler var on StoreView with @Binding var showStore and then declare StoreView(showStore: $viewStore.isShowingStore) in SwiftUI code

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't answer the actual question posed (embedding SKStoreProductViewController inside of an "in-app" modal) but just wanted to post this as a quick alternative for anyone else who has options.

I tried implementing the answers here and had issues with double modals popping up and some crashing on dismiss.

You should consider if you really need this to be an in-app modal... Launching the App Store externally seems optimal in most cases and only requires a couple of lines of code.

```
Button {
    let url = URL(string: ""https://apps.apple.com/app/{app-name}/{app-id}")!
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
} label: {
    Text("View Some App")
}
```